# the code "something ? thing : else" in php

Tags: php, syntax

I'm curious to know what the syntax " : " mean in php I've seen it a couple of times but I can't seem to explain it to myself. Can you also use it in a sentence....or i mean, sample code?

**edit:

sorry folks, I was referring to the ternary operator. Thanks for the other entries as well. I didn't know what to call it at first, apologies.

Comment: That character can be used in multiple contexts. Maybe *you* should use it in a sentence so we can all know what you're really asking about. Copy and paste a couple of lines that demonstrate its use from whatever code you're trying to understand.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you are referring to the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which uses a ? and : as follows:

```
$variable = boolean_expression ? "true_value" : "false_value";
```

This code is shorthand for an if-else:

```
if (boolean_expression) {
   $variable = "true_value";
}
else {
   $variable = "false_value";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
echo ($a == 1 ? "A is 1" : "A is not 1");
```

Answer (score 6):

How about the shorthand syntax for blocks in PHP embedded in HTML? For example

```
<body>
   <h1>Some Header</h1>
   <?php if($somevariable == '4') : ?>
      <h2>Some other thing</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
   <?php else: ?>
      <h3>Else!</h3>
   <?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

Probably doesn't necessarily count as an operator. More of a delimiter here.

Comment: Doesn't *have* to be embedded in HTML, does it? It's simply an alternate syntax for most constructs that would otherwise use braces.

Comment: It was created to get rid of nonsensical braces spread through PHP tags embedded through HTML. If you have a giant block of PHP in HTML (horrors of doing this aside), you wouldn't need to use them. It's just for wrapping chunks of HTML with PHP.

Answer (score 5):

It can also refer to a goto

```
MyGoto:
    if (DoSomething())
        goto MyGoto;
```

Very few circumstances warrant a goto, but that's what it can mean if not a ternary operator.

Comment: Note that the goto operator is only available as of PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

The `?:` operator is a ternary operator called the [conditional operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

It is conditional because the expressions *expr2* and *expr3* in `expr1 ? expr2 : expr3` are evaluated based on the evaluated return value of *expr1*:

- If *expr1* evaluates to *true*, *expr2* is evaluated and the return value of *expr2* is the return value of the whole `?:` operator expression;
- otherwise *expr3* is evaluated and the return value of the `?:` operator expression is the return value of *expr3*.

Here’s an example:

```
echo 1 == 1 ? "true" : "false";
```

If `1 == 1` evaluates to *true*, `"true"` will be echoed, otherwise `"false"`.

Note that the `?:` operator is just *a* and not *the* ternary operator. The word ternary just means that there are three operands (`op1 ? op2 : op3`) just like a binary operator has two operands (e.g. `op1 + op2`, `op1 / op2`, `op1 % op2`, etc.) and unary operators just have one operand (e.g. `!op`, `-op`, `~op`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the conditional operator?

```
$a = $gork === 1 ? $foo : $bar;
```

Check out the "Ternary Operator" section on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

It's basically a short cut for an if else, the above code is the same as:

```
if($gork === 1)
    $a = $foo;
else
    $a = $bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a short-form [conditional expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_statement), known in PHP as the "ternary operator."  See the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) for more details on its usage.

```
echo ($sheLovesMe ? "She loves me!" : "She loves me not!");
```