# Does there exist a shorter if statement in PHP?

Tags: php, language-features, ternary-operator, language-construct

Is it possible to rewrite this to be shorter somehow?

```
if (isset($_POST['pic_action'])){
  $pic_action=$_POST['pic_action'];
}
else { 
  $pic_action=0;
}
```

I have seen it somewhere but forgot... :/

BTW, please explain your code also if you like!

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the [conditional operator `?:`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$pic_action = isset($_POST['pic_action']) ? $_POST['pic_action'] : 0;
```

The conditional operator expression `expr1 ? expr2 : expr3` evaluates to the return value of `expr2` if the evaluated return value of `expr1` is *true*; otherwise the expression evaluates to the evaluated return value of `expr3`. So if `isset($_POST['pic_action'])` evaluates to *true*, the whole expression evaluates to the evaluated value of `$_POST['pic_action']` and to the evaluated value of `0` otherwise.

So in short: if `isset($_POST['pic_action'])` is true, `$pic_action` will hold the value of `$_POST['pic_action']` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: More commonly/also known as the *ternary operator*

Comment: @Justin Johnson: But to be correct it’s just *a* ternary operator and not *the* ternary operator. (Although there doesn’t come any other ternary operator in my mind right now.)

Comment: @Gordon: "Ternary" just describes the number of arguments it involves (3), just as binary operators (`+`, `-`, `/`, etc) involve 2 arguments.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976025/the-code-in-php/1976169#1976169

Comment: @nickf well, it says *Ternary operator* in the manual, which is of course, also a conditional operator. But I'd guess most PHP people will find it easier to know what is meant by the first.
@Gumbo  Sorry. It's your post. Name it it any way you like.

Comment: @Gordon: Never mind. I just don’t want to call it ternary operator although that’s the common term for this operator. But I’m rather useing a less-known term than a in my opinion wrong term.

Answer (score 8):

Gumbo's answer is probably the best way.

It can also be written as:

```
$pic_action = 0;
if (isset($_POST['pic_action'])){
    $pic_action=$_POST['pic_action'];
}
```

Comment: I usually use this one over the ternary operator, because I find it easier to understand what's going on or when there is some more logic to do in the IF block

Comment: I avoid the ternary operator and use this method so that my test coverage is more useful.  While specific values can make certain code fail it is more likely that a missed branch (being the calculation of the value within the if or ternary) will lead to failures.  For the magic 100% code coverage only half of all ternary branches may still be checked.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pic_action=(isset($_POST['pic_action']))?($_POST['pic_action']):0;
```

Comment: All those parenthesis are superfluous.

Comment: @Justin Johnson: I prefer `($pic_action=((isset($_POST['pic_action']))?($_POST['pic_action']):(0)));` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$pic_action = array_get($_POST, 'pic_action', 0);
```

The line above requires the `array_get` function defined below. Source from [Kohana's `Arr` class](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/arr.php). Very small and generic function. Can be used on all arrays, e.g. `$_GET`.

```
/**
 * Retrieve a single key from an array. If the key does not exist in the
 * array, the default value will be returned instead.
 *
 * @param   array   array to extract from
 * @param   string  key name
 * @param   mixed   default value
 * @return  mixed
 */
function array_get(array $array, $key, $default = NULL)
{
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Longer, but reusable:

```
$pic_action = QueryPost('pic_action', 0);

function QueryPost($name, $default='', $valid=false) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$name])) return $default;
    if (($valid) and (empty($_POST[$name]))) return $default;
    return $_POST[$name];
}
```

Or you could have the QueryPost function do a form of validation while you're at it.

```
$pic_action = QueryPost('pic_action', 'int', 0);

function QueryPost($name, $rule, $default='', $valid=false) {
    // this shouldn't be too hard to write
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$_POST['pic_action'] = isset($_POST['pic_action']) ? $_POST['pic_action'] : 0;
```

Comment: No - this would set `$_POST['pic_action']` to either `true` if it is set, or `0` if it is not set. `$x = $y ?: $z` is the equivalent of `$x = $y ? $y : $z`

Comment: @Alix Axel: And you don’t want to change your answer?