# The meaning of ':' and '?'

Tags: php, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [the code “ : ” in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976025/the-code-in-php)

I often see a lot of php code using **?** and **:**, but I don't actually understand what it is for. Here an example:

```
$selected = ($key == $config['default_currency']) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
```

Can someone clear me up, please? :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(condition ? val1 : val2)
```

evaluates to `val1` if `condition` is true, or `val2` if `condition` is false.

---

Since PHP 5.3, you may also see an even more obscure form that leaves out `val1`:

```
(val0 ?: val2)
```

evaluates to `val0` if `val0` evaluates to a non-false value, or `val2` otherwise.  Yikes!

---

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 14):

It's the ternary operator. It's basically a if / else on one line.

For example, those lines :

```
if (!empty($_POST['value'])) {
    $value = $_POST['value'];
} else {
    $value = "";
}
```

can be shortened by this line :

```
$value = (!empty($_POST['value'])) ? $_POST['value'] : "";
```

It can make code easier to read **if you don't abuse it**.

Comment: +1 for **if you don't abuse it**. I've seen many instances of nested ternary conditionals and it makes me want to cry every time.

Comment: +1 to **if you don't abuse it**. (for the love of all that is good, DO NOT NEST!)

Answer (score 2):

It's shorthand for an if statement

You can turn that statement into this:

```
if ($key == $config['default_currency']) {
    $selected = ' selected="selected"';
} else {
    $selected = '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the [ternary conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a), just like in C.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if ($key == $config['default_currency'])
{
   $selected = ' selected="selected"';
}
else
{
   $selected = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode,

```
variable = (condition) ? statement1 : statement2
```

maps to

```
if (condition is true)
then
variable = statement1
else
variable = statement2
end if
```